# Python SQLite3 Writing Filenames to Table, TypeError: 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Hi I’m writing a script with the SQLite3 package that creates a table that stores the filename and file creation date of JPG files in a folder:

```
import sqlite3
import os
import time

conn = sqlite3.connect("DB1.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE images (photoID TEXT, dates TEXT)")

path = r"C:\Users\myname\ImageStore"
photoIDs = []
dates = []
for i in os.listdir(path):
    a = os.stat(os.path.join(path, i))
    dates.append([time.ctime(a.st_ctime)])
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO images VALUES (?, ?)", photoIDs, dates)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I am however getting a TypeError saying that the ‘function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)’. I’m unsure why I’m getting this error and was hoping someone could help me figure out a solution. Thanks :)

P.S. I used the text data type for dates as it was in that format to which my script printed it and that was what will populate the table.

Comment: Please, post the error text as plain text, because you already see it

Comment: executemany requires 2 arguments not 3 - which is exactly what the exception is telling you. See:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

Following the example in the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create table lang (name, first_appeared)")

# This is the qmark style:
cur.execute("insert into lang values (?, ?)", ("C", 1972))

# The qmark style used with executemany():
lang_list = [
    ("Fortran", 1957),
    ("Python", 1991),
    ("Go", 2009),
]
cur.executemany("insert into lang values (?, ?)", lang_list)

# And this is the named style:
cur.execute("select * from lang where first_appeared=:year", {"year": 1972})
print(cur.fetchall())

con.close()
```

You need to pass a list of tuple, for your case it would be something like:

```
# (I don't use loop for comprehension)
photoIDs = [0,1,2]
dates = ["yourdate0", "yourdate1", "yourdate2"] # I don't know your date format
values = [
    (photoIDs[0], dates[0]),
    (photoIDs[1], dates[1]),
    (photoIDs[2], dates[2]),
]
```

Then you can pass `values` to `executemany`.

Answer (score 0):

- You're never assigning to `photoIDs`. It would remain empty.
- You're appending a list into `dates`. You'll want to append the time alone.
- You may wish to consider using ISO8601 dates instead of `ctime`, since `ctime` results are locale-specific and not easily sorted.
- When using `executemany`, the second argument needs to be an iterable of n-tuples, where `n` is the number of `?` placeholders.
- You don't need to run `executemany` in the loop; you'd just run it at the end.
- Your variable naming isn't quite perfect. Why `a`, `i`? Why not `stat_result` and `filename`?

Here's a reworking of your code into two different functional pieces:

- `get_image_names_and_dates()` takes a path, iterates over files in it and returns a dictionary mapping the full path (`C:\Users\myname\ImageStore\foo.jpg`) to an ISO 8601 timestamp string). I could only assume something like that is what you meant with `photoID`.
- The `main()` function calls that function and uses `executemany()` on the returned dict's `.items()` (which, as discussed above, will be an iterable of 2-tuples).

```
import datetime
import os
import sqlite3


def get_image_names_and_dates(path):
    names_and_dates = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        full_filename = os.path.join(path, filename)
        creation_timestamp = os.stat(full_filename).st_ctime
        creation_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(creation_timestamp)
        names_and_dates[full_filename] = creation_datetime.isoformat()
    return names_and_dates


def main():
    path = r"C:\Users\myname\ImageStore"
    names_and_dates = get_image_names_and_dates(path)
    with sqlite3.connect("DB1.db") as conn:
        conn.execute("CREATE TABLE images (photoID TEXT, dates TEXT)")
        conn.executemany("INSERT INTO images VALUES (?, ?)", names_and_dates.items())
        conn.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```